# Firestore: How to update array on a condition and nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

[Image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xertx.png)
I can't seem to modify the convos array on a condition, let alone update the nested values.
Two things I want to do:
Change 'connected' to false given a socketID.
Add an object into messages array given a socketID.
I'm able to add into the convos array and read from the convos array just fine, but I can't update or change anything.

Below is the code which I think was my best attempt

```
const person = {socketID: '123123'};
firebase.firestore().collection("Conversations").doc("x0uio6wWlxEyos6ruc2r")
        .onSnapshot((doc)=> {
          doc.where('socketID', '===', person.socketID)
          .update({
            connected: false
          })
        })
```

I think if I correctly know how to access the convos array inside a specific document, then I should be able to make update changes accordingly.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the socketId unique for all records ? If not where condition matches multiple documents. And you should update them using batch or etc.

Comment: yes it is, all socketIDs are unique

Comment: onSnapshot is mandatory for this approach ?

Comment: I dont think so. But I was able to access my document using onSnapshot and retrieve all the data from the convos array.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply filtering on DocumentData. You may need to manipulate the document over javascript.

```
const data = (await firebase.firestore().collection("Conversations").doc("x0uio6wWlxEyos6ruc2r").get()).data();
const manipulatedData = data.find(x => x.socketID == person.socketID).connected = false;     
firebase.firestore().collection("Conversations").doc("x0uio6wWlxEyos6ruc2r").set(manipulatedData, { merge: true });
```

You may need to make small changes to the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
update({
  connected : false,
  messages : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(object)
})
```

And to remove element use `arrayRemove`

Comment: thank you for the reply. How do I add a condition given the way the database is setup. The condition being for a specified socketID.